# Iterate string.append over rows Python

Tags: python, string, iterator, append

I have a data set like this:
[image] and the objective is to have each cell of the data frame in one list whereby each cell is a word in itself.

I have tried originally with:

```
string = []
for words in data:
    string.append(words)
```

but it gives me the wanted result for the first row only:
[image].

I have tried also to iterate it using iterrows but it creates just pairs of value not very useful.

How I can iterate the append function over all the rows and store the results as a single string?

Comment: did you try printing data itself? Or you try to print len(data) and check whether expected list is assigned to data variable

Comment: Can you add details about how you read the data? What is the type of data? What the output should look like?

Comment: It is a data frame from an excel file. No field names ( I have used it for Association Rules). I need to do some descriptive statistics of the term frequency. The trick here is that in this case the term is not a tokenised type but each cell needs to be treated as a term in itself. I did not try to print the data I want just to have all the 64 rows in one big list of strings as the example posted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:

```
string = []
for words in data.itertuples(index=False):
    string += words
```